# http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ email not working

Tags: 11.10, brainstorm

I've created a new account on http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ with a correct email.
But never received any email with the password. So I cannot connect.

Please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Ubuntu Brainstorm closed permanently in 2014.

Answer (score 3):

1. Have you checked your spam folder?
2. Have you tried to do a [password reset?](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/user/password)
3. If the above failed: have you tried to create a new user?
4. If all of the above fails, you can try to [contact the moderators](https://launchpad.net/~brainstorm-moderators)  of brainstorm.ubuntu.com.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct, according to the current Brainstorm Admin.